# How to pass data to a child component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am learning `vue.js` and the answer to my question is in the [documentation for dynamic props](https://vuejs.org/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Props). I however fail to have in working in practice for my data structure.

My intent is to have a custom component `<cell>` fed with data from the `Vue` instance:

```js
Vue.component('cell', {
  props: cell,
  template: '<div>day is {{ cell.name }}</div>'
})

new Vue({
  el: '#container',
  data: {
    "week": {
      "today": {
        "name": "Monday"
      },
      "tomorrow": {
        "name": "Tuesday"
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.0.3/vue.js"></script>

<div id="container">
  <cell v-bind:cell="week.today"></cell>
  <cell v-bind:cell="week.tomorrow"></cell>
</div>
```

(this snippet does not run at all, not sure if vue.js is supported. I also have [a JSFiddle to test on](https://jsfiddle.net/WoJWoJ/11cj0Lx6/))

The expected result is

```
<div>day is Monday</div>
<div>day is Tuesday</div>
```

The output is empty, so I believe that there is something fundamentally wrong with my code. What is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`props` must be an array or object, so basically:

```
props: ['cell']
```

or

```
props: {
   cell: {
     // options
   }
}
```

but **not**:

```
props: cell
```

I've fixed the fiddle for you here:

https://jsfiddle.net/11cj0Lx6/3/